# Trying to understand the definition of the limit of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If $a \in \mathbb{R}$ is the limit of the sequence $\{x_n\}$, then necessarily the following takes place (it's just the definition of the limit of a sequence):

$$\forall \varepsilon > 0\quad \exists N_{\varepsilon} \in \mathbb{N} : |x_n  -a | < \epsilon \qquad \forall n \geq N_{\varepsilon}$$

I thought I understood this definition, but that was till the moment our teacher asked us whether or not from the statement below necessarily follows that $a$ is the limits of $\{x_n\}$

$$\exists N \in \mathbb{N} : \forall \varepsilon > 0 \implies |x_n  -a | < \epsilon \quad \forall n \geq N$$

I'm not sure if I'm am able to see the difference.

According to me, from the statement above not necessarily follows that $a$ is the limit of $\{x_n\}$, because $N$ is not chosen after picking the number $\varepsilon > 0$. That is, we can chose some $N^*\in \mathbb{N}$ such that

$$\exists b \in \mathbb{N}\quad \forall\varepsilon > 0 \implies |x_n  -b | <|x_n  -a | < \epsilon \quad \forall N_{\varepsilon} \geq n \geq N^*$$

So

$$|x_n  -b | <|x_n  -a | $$
$$|x_n|  -|b | <|x_n|  -|a | $$
$$|b | > |a | \implies |b | \neq |a |$$

That is a may be the limit of one of the subsequences of $\{x_n\}$ of but not the limit of $\{x_n\}$

Comment: Think about the following sentences:  in every math class, there is someone who get A grade & there is someone who get A grade in every math class

Comment: @NickLiu I guess: in every math class, there is someone who get A $\implies$  that someone may not be the same all the time. there is someone who get A grade in every math class  $\implies$ is the same student all the time

Comment: @NickLiu that would imply that, under the second statement of my question, $\forall N^*\in \mathbb{N}$ where $N^* \neq N$ the inequality $|x_n  -a | < \epsilon$ may not hold, even if $N^* > N$? (That is, i'm chosing ''other student'', who may not get an A in every math class). Do I get it right?

Comment: well, i want to point out that my second sentence is much more harsher than the first sentence, that is, first sentence implies the second, but the second does not imply to the first all the time. Consider the answer below by @Matias Heikkilä, if the first sentence implies the second, then there would be some $N$ such that $1/N=0$, which is wrong

Comment: Please don't write things like $\forall x \exists y \,(\text{something involving }x,y,z)\,\forall z$. Quantifiers must always come _before_ the formula they quantify; otherwise their order is not clear, and _the order of quantifiers matters_. There's no telling whether the intended meaning of your formula is $$\forall z \forall x \exists y \,(\text{something involving }x,y,z)\\\forall x \forall z \exists y \,(\text{something involving }x,y,z)\\\forall x \exists y\forall z \,(\text{something involving }x,y,z)$$ and not making that clear defeats the entire purpose of symbolic quantifiers.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily prove that $\forall \varepsilon > 0 \quad \left| x_n -a \right| < \varepsilon$ implies that $x_n = a$. Now think about e.g. $x_n = \frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: I've tried to elaborate from what you and @NickLiu have pointed out.

My attempt:

By the Archemedean Property we have that $\forall \varepsilon > 0\quad \exists n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{n}< \varepsilon |x_n -a|$. On the other hand we have that $\forall \varepsilon > 0$ such that $|x_n -a| < \varepsilon \implies x_n = a \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. Therefore we have that $\exists n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{n}< \varepsilon |x_n -a| = 0$, which contradicts the Archemedean Property.

Do I get it?